# MySQL query to get sum of differences between column and AVG of same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which contains the scores by user, for a game:

```
UserID (Integer)
MatchId (Integer)
Score (Double)
```

> I'd like to getter sum each user's "points above average" (PAA) - the
>   amount by which a user's score was above or below the average.
>
> So you'd need to calculate the average of 'Score' for each 'MatchId',
>   then for each row in the table calculate the amount by which the
>   'Score' differs from the match average. And then sum that PAA value by
>   user.

Is it possible to do this via a MySQL query? Or do I need PHP? If it can be done by query, what would that query look like?

Comment: What kind of game involves floating point values? Even gymnastics makes do with DECIMALs

Comment: You should show your attempt first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**plan**

> - compute avg scores by match
> - join user scores to avg scores and compute sum of derived difference field by userid

---

**setup**

```
create table scores
(
  UserID integer not null,
  MatchId integer not null,
  Score decimal(5, 2) not null,
  primary key ( UserID, MatchId )
);

insert into scores
( UserID, MatchId, Score )
values
( 1, 1, 22.1 ),
( 2, 1, 36.0 ),
( 3, 1, 35.3 ),
( 1, 2, 50.0 ),
( 2, 2, 39.8 ),
( 3, 2, 42.0 )
;
```

**query**

```
select s.UserID, sum(s.Score - avgs.avg_score) as paa
from scores s
inner join
(
select MatchId, avg(Score) as avg_score
from scores
group by MatchId
) avgs
on s.MatchId = avgs.MatchId
group by s.UserID
;
```

**output**

```
+--------+-----------+
| UserID |    paa    |
+--------+-----------+
|      1 | -2.966666 |
|      2 | 0.733334  |
|      3 | 2.233334  |
+--------+-----------+
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bedee/1)**